# wordpress excerpt execute shortcode?

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I'm new in wordpress.

So, i create shortcode to get data in functions.php and use it in post.

```
function create_shortcode_test {   
..... 
return my_data;
}
add_shortcode ( 'test_shortcode' , 'create_shortcode_test' );

[test_shortcode]
```

And i use excerpt for post.

```
example
```

In homepage, i can see excerpt.

After open post, i can see data get with shortcode.

But i want to know:

In homepage post show excerpt and shortcode working

or post just show excerpt, shortcode not working. And after open post shortcode working.

That mean i want to know, if i choice show excerpt, in homepage (just see excerpt), shortcode in post (not in excerpt) working or not working () in homepage ?

Comment: cant understand what are you trying to say

Comment: This is very hard to understand. You might want to replace ..... with your actual code so at least the reader can see by the code what you are trying to do.

Comment: That mean shortcode executed with post (post just show excerpt can see in homepage) or open post execute shortcode. shortcode executed or not with excerpt is on?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple method to display the_excerpt as this tag comes under the loop..

```
function create_shortcode_test {    
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>    
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    }

add_shortcode ( 'test_shortcode' , 'create_shortcode_test' );
```

Comment: I just want to know in homepage, shortcode executed to get data and post just show excerpt, or post just show excerpt and after open it, shortcode execute to get data? That mean shortcode executed or not with using excerpt?

Comment: do u mean you want only excerpt in home page??

Comment: Yes, that i mean. I want to know in homepage post just show excerpt and shortcode working or post just show excerpt shortcode not working, and after open post shortcode working.

Comment: mate shortcode will work according to the format you have shown its just how you manipulate the things according to your needs

Comment: So, if i choice show excerpt, in homepage (just see excerpt), shortcode in post (not in excerpt) working or not working () ?

Comment: So, if i choice show excerpt, in homepage (just see excerpt), shortcode in post (not in excerpt) working or not working () in homepage ?